# Permission to show sidebar on load

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have some Google documents with scripts that should automatically load a custom sideboard when the document is opened.

That did work well some time. But I do not get it to work anymore.

```
function onOpen() {
    DocumentApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Custom Menu')
        .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
    showSidebar();
}

function showSidebar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
        .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
        .setWidth(300);
    DocumentApp.getUi()
        .showSidebar(html);
}
```

The log shows, that I do not have the permission to run `showSidebar()`.

But I did authorize it. And it does work, when I choose "Show Sidebar" from the custom menu or when i run `onOpen`.

How can I get the permission for `showSidebar()` for onload?

Comment: Try moving showSideBar to an installed on open trigger.

Comment: Simple `onOpen()` cannot have permission to `showSidebar()`

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was a time when simple triggers did open SideBars I believe.  But with recent changes in security you should use an installable  open trigger.

Comment: @TheWizEd self-answers cannot be accepted immediately. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/